# How to directly print JSON recieved in GET Request Body in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My intention is to make a GET request using the [DIO](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) or any similar HTTP client in order to receive a JSON data/body and print it to the console.

I have written the following code to achieve that.

```
fetchQuestion(String userIdentifier) async {
        String urlToCall =
            "someURLhere";

        try {
          Response response = await Dio().get(
            urlToCall,
            options: Options(headers: {
              HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer " + userIdentifier,
            }),
          );

          print(response.data);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
```

The problem with this code is, when I print `response.data`, only `null` is printed. Even though I am certain that the response data contains a JSON file.

I have checked on the backend, and I am getting a `200` status code. Additionally, printing `response.headers` **does** print the headers I expected. It is only the `response.body` that prints `null`.

Issues I have tried include

1. Using `print(utf8.decode(response.data));`
2. Using `json.decode(response.data)` -> In which case I get
   `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.` error.

I would appreciate any kind of help regarding printing the JSON file received.

Answer (score 2):

Have you printed just response to see what fields are in there.
I haven't used DIO but http package works fine for me:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
...    
final response = await http.get(Url);
```

Comment: Printing `(response)` using DIO prints `null`. But the same request, when implemented using http package prints a `future` reference. Is there any way to stall the print until the future becomes available?

Comment: Ya, I had to use FutureBuilder and snapshot to get access to the actual data.